# Ask a variable what data type it is in C++

Tags: c++, variables, type-conversion

I was wondering if you could ask a variable what data type it is in C++?
I also know Scheme, and there you just do something like this:

```
(define x 5)
(number? x)
```

And it will return 'true'.
Is something like this possible in C++?

Comment: In C++ and other statically typed languages you do not ask a variable what its type is, you tell the variable what's its type is going to be. There are ways to access information about the type (see answers below).

Comment: You *probably* don't need this. C++ is a statically typed language. Variables have type, and you *know* what that type is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No such metadata is stored on C++ variables. An `int` is just an `int`, it takes exactly the number of bytes required for an `int`, and no extra information that would allow you to find its type.

Moreover, a variable in C++ is just a chunk of memory. You can address it as an `int`, as an array of `char`s, as a `struct` etc. Nothing will prevent you from taking a pointer to an `int` and casting it to `char`. So what is its type then? `int`? `char`? Actually nothing, types in C++ are just a way of interpreting the bytes residing in the memory.

Comment: That's almost correct. There is some type info stored in the vtable (if there is one).

Comment: @TobiasBrandt Do I understand correctly that this is true for class fields but not for local variables?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether they are fields or local variables, it's the type that matters. If the field/variable is a reference or pointer to a class that has at least one virtual function, you can get type information with `typeid(*var)`. The rationale is that you need to store the function pointers for the virtual functions somewhere anyway, so you might as well put a pointer to a type info struct in there too.

Answer (score 7):

The C++ equivalent would probably be something like this:

```
auto x = 5;
using x_type = decltype(x);
```

And you can check it with

```
if( std::is_same<x_type,int>::value ) ...
```

But I am not sure this is what you have in mind, since C++ is statically typed. There is also dynamic typing when you have a class hierarchy:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() {} };
struct Derived1 : Base {};
struct Derived2 : Base {};

int main()
{
    Base* p = new Derived2;
    if( dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(p) ) { /* is Derived1 */ }
    else if( dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(p) ) { /* is Derived2 */ }
    else { /* neither */ }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if you could ask a variable what data type it is in C++?

<s>Not for primitives</s> (such as your "number", which would be an integer). For polymorphic classes, it is possible using [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information).

Actually, there's a method which works for primitives: the `typeid` operator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << typeid(i).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not just "classes;"  they have to be polymorphic.

Comment: @JohnDibling Correct, will add it.

Comment: Note that this only works for primitives because the type is statically know. If you do, e.g.,  `void *j = &i; typeid(*j)` you will not get the desired result.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt Yes, that's probably John Dibling meant by "typeid only works for polymorphic types".

Answer (score 2):

On compile time, you have `decltype`. `decltype(expression)` will yield the type of the expression.

If you want information on runtime, you should use RTTI (Runtime Type Information) with things like [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) and [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index).

`std::type_info` allows you to get class names on runtime for example.

You get the `type_info` by using the `typeid` operator. (It will return an `std::type_info const&`)

Answer (score 0):

Only in a very very limited way. If the type of the variable is user defined (class or struct) and the class/struct has at least one virtual method, you can use the [typeid operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf39xec.aspx) to get runtime type information. Note that it will give you the static type (i.e. the declared type of the variable) if it is not of class/struct type or doesn't have virtual methods.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  There is a `typeid` operator, but this only works for polymorphic types, which `int` and other native types are not.

There is also `decltype` which evaluates to the type of a declaration, but I doubt this is really what you're after.

Moreover, this isn't really the C++ Way of doing things.  C++ is a staticly typed language, unlike many other languages where the type of a variable is meant to be nearly irrelevant.  One of the founding principles of C++ is type safety, where the type of a variable is *known* and *is not ambigious.*

If you find yourself writing C++ code and need to use some kind of mechanism to discover the type of something, I'd say it's likely you're fighting the language.  Don't try to use C++ to write Scheme code.

Comment: Is this a GCC/clang extension if `typeid` worked on an `int` for me?

Comment: @H2CO3:  I suspect it must be.  I could be wrong; I *never* use this.